# Smart @IntDef Annotation with switch in return function

Tags: android

I use the following *@IntDef* declaration:

```
@IntDef({ViewTypes.TYPE_RECIPE, ViewTypes.TYPE_CAMPAIGN, ViewTypes.TYPE_INFO})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface ViewTypes {
    int TYPE_RECIPE = 0;
    int TYPE_CAMPAIGN = 1;
    int TYPE_INFO = 2;
}
```

And this method which returns one of these ints based on the position:

```
@ViewTypes
public int getType(int position) {
    if (position < 3) {
        return ViewTypes.TYPE_RECIPE;
    } else if (position < 5) {
        return ViewTypes.TYPE_CAMPAIGN;
    } else {
        return ViewTypes.TYPE_INFO;
    }
}
```

I use that method in a switch to return something:

```
public View getView(int position) {
    switch (getType(position)) {
        case ViewTypes.TYPE_RECIPE:
            return getRecipeView(position);
        case ViewTypes.TYPE_CAMPAIGN:
            return getCampaignView(position);
        case ViewTypes.TYPE_INFO:
            return getInfoView();
    }
    return null; // <-- unreachable 
}
```

Now I assume that when I "case" all possible *ViewTypes* that the Annotation knows that I don't need the last line("return null"). In fact it is unreachable, isn't it?. If I remove the "return null" I get the error "Missing return statement".

Edit:
I just figured out that I can actually return e.g. "5" in the getType function and it would mark the "5" with a red error message "Must be one of...". But the app still builds. So is there a way to make that to an compile error instead of a "warning"?

Comment: if you are so sure then replace `case ViewTypes.TYPE_INFO` with `default` ... or just throw an exception that you have uknown type instead return statement

Comment: Good point thanks. I could do that.. I just figured out that I can actually return e.g. "5" in the getType function and it would mark the "5" with a red error message "Must be one of...". But the app still builds.

Comment: Did you tried `lintOptions {  warningsAsErrors true }`

Comment: It didn't work for me. I am still able to build the project, weird.

Comment: Probably I should write a feature request to google.

Comment: ok one more try `lintOptions { error 'ResourceType'}` ... do you have any `lintOptions` in gradle? or maybe `lintOptions { fatal 'ResourceType'}`